# How to make xPages name picker to show Corporate Directory or Extended Directory Catalog Names?

Tags: javascript, xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

I have a simple name picker:

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="myNameEditBox">
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:dominoNABNamePicker
            valueNameFormat="common" 
            people="true" 
            nameList="people" 
            groups="false" 
            addressBookSel="all">
        </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

but it brings only names from servers names.nsf that may not have persons in (the server where the app runs). So I need to make it work like in Notes Client

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xe:namePickAggregator to lookup over multiples address books

```
<xe:namePicker
    id="namePicker1"
    for="inputText1">
    <xe:this.dojoAttributes>
        <xp:dojoAttribute
            name="maxRowCount"
            value="10000">
        </xp:dojoAttribute>
    </xe:this.dojoAttributes>
    <xe:this.dataProvider>
        <xe:namePickerAggregator>
            <xe:this.dataProviders>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker
                    addressBookDb="server!!nab1.nsf"
                    addressBookSel="db-name"
                    groups="false"
                    people="true"
                    valueNameFormat="common">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
                <xe:dominoNABNamePicker
                    addressBookDb="names.nsf"
                    addressBookSel="db-name"
                    groups="false"
                    people="true"
                    valueNameFormat="common">
                </xe:dominoNABNamePicker>
            </xe:this.dataProviders>
        </xe:namePickerAggregator>
    </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```